# error: Unable to update registry `crates-io` while cargo build-bpf

Tags: build-bpf, wsl

I just started learning solona. And following the solana guide

while learning Cargo build-bpf, i am getting following error on wsl 2, Debian

```
biplab@BIPLAB:/mnt/d/Rust/rust_project/solana$ cargo build-bpf
   Updating crates.io index
error: Unable to update registry `crates-io`

Caused by:
 failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
 network failure seems to have happened
 if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
 https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli

Caused by:
 SSL error: unknown error; class=Ssl (16)
```

i have tried some of the online debug fix like setting netgit-fetch-with-cli to true
but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your machine is having difficulties accessing the internet. Be sure that you have a working internet connection from your shell. The error message says it all, along with a potential way to fix it:

```
Caused by:
 network failure seems to have happened
 if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
 https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli
```